# php how to add a reference

Tags: php, c++, php-extension

i would like to ask how to convert: `method(Class1::Class2 &class);` in php?
what should i write:  `me->method(????)`

hx. appreciate

I am working in c__/ubuntu.

Comment: *(related)* http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way:

```
function method(&$variable)
```

However, if `&class` is an object, it's not necessary - since PHP 5, objects are automatically <strike>passed as reference.</strike> [a kind of references in themselves](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php), so this isn't necessary.

Comment: Nitpicking on "passed as reference": http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php ;-)

Comment: i am trying to create a php extension. How to convert this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384848/how-to-create-a-configuration-file-for-a-php-extension-when-having-nested-classes